# Baking a wheel, the new texture did not bake the light

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I am trying to bake a texture, but the image did not copy the light, would you know why?

[image]

[image]

[image]

The blend file : [image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with how you have this bake setup, but both should cause issues much more significant than that it just didn't receive light.

1. The low poly intersects the high poly, and no amount of ray extusion is appropriate for the low poly you have created.  You need to use a cage.
2. The UV map has overlapping faces.

In addition to this, you didn't pack any texture images with the file, so I had to bake with a flat color.

When I fix these problems, the bake receives light just fine:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand. What is "using a cage" ? As for the overlapping faces, I did a "project from view" in order to go faster, is that what you mean?

Comment: @oath__ I would recommend looking at a few more normal baking tutorials.  Yes, a project from view unwrap is wholly inappropriate for any kind of texture bake.  For cages, I'd recommend starting by searching for "blender bake cage tutorial" someplace.